# Get FindBugs to report errors separately

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, findbugs

i don't quite know how to phrase it, but my problem is this - I want a separate error list for FindBugs aside from "regular" errors in my projects.

Right now, i've moved FindBugs' errors to Info category, so it is kinda separate. But I can't differentiate between warning levels of FindBugs' problems.

Is there a way to have a separate hierarchy of errors found by FindBugs?

If there is not, please, recommend some other tool with similar capabilities of "sonaring" my code.

UPD: I know of Bug Explorer view, but stuff is displayed there AND in the Problems view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second **Problems** view configured to show only those from FindBugs using the view's context menu (downward triangle next to the minimize button pictured in the first screenshot below).

1. Bring up the **Problems** view.
2. Select **New Problems View** from the context menu.
3. In the new tab, select **Configure Contents...** from the context menu.

This will bring up a dialog containing the filtering options (second screenshot below).

4. Uncheck **Show all items** to enable the other options.
5. Click the **Deselect All** button next to the **Types** list in the lower right.
6. Check each of the **FindBugs** types in that same list.
7. Click **OK** to save the configuration.

**Problems View Context Menu**

[image: Problem view filter]

**Configure Contents Dialog**

[image: Configure contents]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the problems and warnings, as indicated in the other answer. But if you do not want to switch filters back and forth all the time, you can even create a second instance of the problems view (using the view menu of the problems view) and have that second instance show only the Findbugs issues, independent of what your "main" problems view is showing.